# Powershell- Multi line search, find two different strings, return only matched lines

Tags: regex, powershell, multiline

Data:

```
{
    "blah1":blah,
    "name":"hostname",
    "blah2":blah,
    "blah3":[{
      "blah4":blah,
      "blah5":blah,
    }],
    "blah6":blah,
    "blah7":blah,
    "osName":"OS Type",
    "blah8":blah,
    "blah9":blah,
  }
```

The above repeats itself and I would like to search for the values "name" and the "osName." Below is what I have:

```
$Path = [io.file]::ReadAllText("$FilePath\list.txt")
$regex = '(?m)name":"(.*)".*\n.*osname":"(.*)"'
$list = $Path | Select-String $regex -AllMatches |Foreach { $_.Matches } | Foreach { $_.Groups } |Foreach { $_.Value }
```

My desired output would be to return hosts that have specific OS types. So, one of my searches would be like this:

```
$regex = '(?m)name":"(.*)".*\n.*osname":"Linux"'
    $list = $Path | Select-String $regex -AllMatches |Foreach { $_.Matches } | Foreach { $_.Groups[1] } |Foreach { $_.Value }
```

The above would only return all of the hosts with the OsType of Linux. In the future, I might want to have a search that could be used to search for each "blah" line and return only matched queries. I can't seem to figure out how to search for more than 1 string in a multiline file.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks as awlays

Comment: You should not be using regex to parse a JSON file. `ConvertFrom-Json` will help you extract the information.

Comment: Yes it is. Do I need to convert the file into another format?

Comment: This in not valid json either since you have removed some data. Is the real data properly quoted?

Comment: I had to remove data, but it is in json format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regex is great and has its uses but if you have properly structured data it is worth looking for means of dealing with that data. Assuming your file was properly formatted JSON you should be using `Convert-FromJSON` to convert it into a PowerShell object. Then a simple `Select` *should* get you the data you need

```ps
$jsonObject = [io.file]::ReadAllText("$FilePath\list.txt") | ConvertFrom-Json
$jsonObject | Select name,osname
```

For the first line you could also have done...

```
$jsonObject = Get-Content "$FilePath\list.txt" | Out-String | ConvertFrom-Json
```

Or if you had at least v3

```
$jsonObject = Get-Content "$FilePath\list.txt" -Raw | ConvertFrom-Json
```

Running with some sample data

```
[{
  "id": 1,
  "name": "medwards0",
  "osName": "Windows"
}, {
  "id": 2,
  "name": "ecooper1",
  "osName": "Linux"
}, {
  "id": 3,
  "name": "jmccoy2",
  "osName": "Windows"
}]
```

I get the following results in console

```
name      osName 
----      ------ 
medwards0 Windows
ecooper1  Linux  
jmccoy2   Windows
```

The great thing is now you can do simple filters with `Where-Object` to get the data you are looking for

```
$jsonObject | Where-Object{$_.OsName -eq "Linux"}
```

Comment: Your suggestion isn't working for some reason. The jsonobject has the data, but my searches don't return any results. I even converted the file to json (I'm using an API call to get the data) and ascii encoded it to make sure it's formatted correctly. No luck...

Comment: I just tried your data and it works. My json data is different than yours in that I think it has a depth of 2 or more since when I search for the overall value, hosts, I get all of the data back.        {"hosts":[{"blah":blah,.........}

Comment: If you don't provide sample data that accurately portrays your real data, then you are going to have to tweak any solution that is provided.

Comment: @JimBob If nothing else experiment with `ConvertFrom-Json` and `Get-Member` with just your raw data. See if you get object returned. Might need to delve deeper. I can't help if you don't show your data though

Comment: I do apologize for the lack of sample data, but I can't show it all. When I manually remove "hosts" and it's curly braces from my data, your solution works. {"hosts":[{"blah....]}} doesn't work, [{"blah...}] works. It looks like I will need to trim my data before I search for it. Thank you for your help.

Comment: My comment wasn't intended as a criticism, just pointing out a reality.

Comment: You don't need to trim the data hole point of my answer was to try and get away from that. Let me see if I can guess. `$jsonObject = Get-Content "$FilePath\list.txt" | Out-String | ConvertFrom-Json | Select -Expand Hosts | Select Name, OsName`